# python 2.7.5 failed to build module when install the gentoo prefix

Tags: linux, python-2.7, gentoo

I tried to install the `gentoo prefix` on my [lfs](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) 32bit. But it comes error:

> Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules
>   were not found:
>   _bsddb             _sqlite3           _tkinter         bsddb185           dl                 nis              sunaudiodev
>   To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for
>   the module's name.
>
> Failed to build these modules: crypt

It comes in the last step `emerge -e system`.
If you need any question. Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `mv $EPREFIX/tmp/usr/lib/libpython2.7.a $EPREFIX/tmp/usr/lib/_libpython2.7.a` as mentioned from the following link:
http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-890016-start-0.html

Also look at this post for resolving some of the modules if the above doesn't work:
http://www.kelvinwong.ca/tag/python-2-7/

Comment: hmm.the first method didn't work for me. Because i find i have nothing in the $EPREFIX/tmp directory. Then which package should i installed for the crypt module?